# How to pass $stateParams from ui-router to service in resolve?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I have a route to retrieve a single post and a service to query my API to do so. But I need to pass parameters from the URL to the service so that I can call the API properly. I cannot wrap my head around how to do that.

This is what I have come up with so far. I left out what seemed not relevant for this question.

Thanks for your help!

**The routing**

```
myModule.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  '$locationProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $stateProvider
      .state('post', {
        url: '/posts/:hash_id/:slug',
        templateUrl: '/js/app/views/post.html',
        controller: 'PostCtrl',
        resolve: {
          postPromise: ['posts', function(posts, $stateParams){
            //returns undefined
            console.log($stateParams);
            return posts.getOne($stateParams);
          }]
        }
      })
// etc
```

**The service**

```
myModule.factory('posts', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = {
    posts: [],
    post: {}
  };
  o.getOne = function(params) {
    // Returns undefined
    console.log(params);
    return $http.get('/api/v1/posts/' + params.hash_id).success(function(data){
      angular.copy(data, o.post);
    });
  };
  return o;
}])
```

Comment: You never include `$stateParams` in the `postPrimise` string dependencies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You missed to add `$stateParams` dependency in `postPromise` resolve

**Code**

```
postPromise: ['posts', '$stateParams', function(posts, $stateParams){
```