# How to pass a parameter into a new tab in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a search screen, I want to open new tab when user click search button and I want to pass the search criteria into the new tab.

my code

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    parent: 'app',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    },
    params : {propertyType: null}
})

var url = $state.href('home', { propertyType:2 });
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

This is not working

Comment: the window.open syntax is window.open(URL,name,specs,replace) and may be blocked by browsers, it's better to use a anchor, e.g. <a href="url + '?serachQuery=TODO'" target="_blank">Search</a> to open a new tab. Pass your search query using the url

Comment: use $stateParams which is available from angular-ui-router-v13 onwards. With that you can access stateParams.propertyType in next page.

Comment: @Nishi Not working

Comment: you need to inject $stateparam in controller

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056881/how-to-pass-stateparams-from-ui-router-to-service-in-resolve